# Syntax Highlighter for Diff files in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, command-line, diff

Although I can compare files in IntelliJ IDEA, I can't make use of syntax highlighting of an existing diff file. The file would show as plain text. I have tried with diff and patch extensions.

I have tried to find a plugin for this numerous times, but with no luck.

Why can't we have a syntax highlighter for diff files when we have them for almost all languages.

Also, I can open diff from **Command Line**

```
idea diff <file1> <file2>
```

But can't do so for two revisions for a CVS like

```
idea diff master feature
idea diff master...feature
```

Is there a way to do that from command line?

**NOTE**: Only Command line answers please. I am an avid command line user and like to do most of my repetitive stuff using command line. This saves the resources in my device and also a lot of clicks/keystrokes.

Comment: I'd suggest splitting the second part off to a new question, as it's quite a different topic (and doesn't fit the title).  I think the answer is that the `idea diff` command only supports diffing two concrete files, and doesn't support accessing git data.

Answer (score 0):

select two files in project press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: I don't have the original files. I only have a diff or a patch file. Want to see in syntax highlight to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for rendering diff/patch files called [Diff / Patch File Support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18612-diff--patch-file-support):

and a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74005) for adding it to the IDE as a core capability.